# String variable returned object in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with a variable string but return `[Object object]`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".story-area > h1").text(function () {
        return $(this).text(convertString($(this).text()));
    });

    $(".story-area > p").text(function () {
        return $(this).text(convertString($(this).text()));
    });

    $(".story-area > div > p").text(function () {
        return $(this).text(convertString($(this).text()));
    });
});


function convertString(current_text) {
    var arr_text = current_text.split(' ');
    var new_text = '';
    for (i = 0; i < arr_text.length; i++) {
        if (arr_text[i].length > 4) {
            new_text += arr_text[i].replace(/[Hh][Ii]/g, 'HIV') + ' ';
        } else {
            new_text += arr_text[i] + ' ';
        }
    }
    return new_text;
}
```

The new_text value returns `[Object object]` instead of the string value. Any errors on my code?

[image]

Comment: Uggh, what do you mean? It is replacing the texts for the specified jquery object

Comment: I did a jsfiddle and your function seems works : http://jsfiddle.net/alex3165/Lqsdb0nz/

Comment: how did you conclude that `new_text` is `[Object object]`? `$(this).text(convertString($(this).text()))` is an object.

Comment: Just edited my question with the screenshot of my output. @kalyptusprod

Comment: FIWIW, the whole code can be simplified to `$(".story-area > h1, .story-area > p, .story-area > div > p").text(convertString)`. Also why don't you link to the fiddle, or better create a runnable demo here?

Comment: it worked! Thank you so much @Teemu!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AH, you are setting the text inside of setting the text! You are treating text() as an each.

```
$(".story-area > h1").text(function () {
    return convertString($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: This worked! But someone already mentioned this earlier but thank you!!